# Google Analytics how to track fake pageview?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How do I create a fake pageview in GA?

Example

```
<a href="#" onclick=>"javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/billigst_klik');">Track</a>
```

Then GA would track one pageview named `"billigst_klik"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function track(someurl){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', someurl]);
}

<a href="#" onclick="track('/billigst_klik');">Track</a>
```

But if you are tracking just clicks, it should be an event not a pageview.

```
function trackEvent(someurl){
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click', 'Link_Click', someurl]);
}

<a href="#" onclick="trackEvent('/billigst_klik');">Track</a>
```

Click is the `category` and Link_Click is the `action`. someurl is the `label`. You can set them to be whatever values makes sense to you.

Guide to [Google Analytics Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

Comment: There should be an underscore before `trackPageview`, i.e. `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', someurl]);`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the newer async code? If so, something like this should work:

```
<a href="???" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/billigst_klik']); return false;">Track</a>
```

Comment: How to make a function so that I would just write example onlclick"track('someurl');"? I am using the standard GA code

Comment: @Railsbeginner jk already gave a good explanation of this in their answer. As a side note, the async code is the standard code and if you are not using it I would seriously consider switching.